# Encoding/decoding decimal values in variable-bitwidth binary blocks

Tags: php, encoding, bit-manipulation, binary-data

I'm trying to build a variable-bitwidth binary encoder/decoder for a protocol in a networked personal project I'm designing... and my stupid brain has completely jammed up on how to grasp variable-bitwidth binary encoding/decoding. I've been staring at the same ~18 SLOC for about four days now and I still feel utterly out of my depth. I do feel I should be able to grasp this, but unfortunately my brain randomly conks out when I try to track diverse numeric relationships :(

Theoretically, what I want to do is incredibly simple. I declare a list of bitwidths, and the value I want to store within that bitwidth, like so:

```
[10 bits]: 1013
[1  bit ]: 1
[2  bits]: 3
[19 bits]: 51209
```

Taking the bitwidths into account, the values would be progressively sequenced into a binary string like so:

```
               1 bit
               | 2 bits  
               | ||  
  /-10 bits--\ | \/ /------ 19 bits ------\  
  12345678  12 3 45 678  12345678  12345678  
  11111101  01 1 11 000  11001000  00001001  
  \----------/ | \/ \---------------------/
      1012     1  3          51209
```

The bitstream in bold above is what I transmit down the wire:

```
11111101  253  FD
01111000  120  78
11001000  200  C8
00001001    9  09
```

At the other end, I map the list `{10, 1, 2, 19}` (the set of bitwidths denoted at the top) against the sequence of bytes I've received, which then leaves me with the original set of values I wanted to transmit.

While this is primarily a general algorithmic question and the semantics of any particular language are arguably irrelevant, I should mention that I'm using PHP for this - and part of the reason I'm so stuck is that I'm trying to work out how to avoid resorting to string manipulation, which PHP seems to be obsessively inclined to encourage one to favor over proper numeric processing. However, this function will (hopefully) be processing data at 2-to-3-digit-Mbps speeds, and I want the routines to be as fast as possible. (Incidentally, I'd use another language, but PHP is the one I know the most >_>)

I do understand the basics of binary, and I should stress that I do actually have a working encoder, I think (it outputs the binary data backwards) - but I have no real idea what I'm doing here. I'm not asking "how do I write this function," I'm asking "what are the structural mechanics of what I'm doing and how do I even grasp this."

I should also note that this problem isn't a thinly disguised homework exercise; it's for the network library component in a personal software project I'm designing that, hopefully, will teach me about networking, event handling, and concurrency. Hopefully I can grasp all the other things I'll need to implement... lol

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Please add what you already have tried/attempts and show for what you are looking for (As specific as you can describe it)!

Answer (score 2):

To give you a little startpoint how such a binary decoder/encoder could look like here an example:

So now what's the concept behind this?

Pretty simple I loop through each data which you want to send and split them up into single bytes. So as an example:

```
data:    1013
bitMask:   10
```

So I first calculate how many bytes it takes to send it. Here this would be 2 bytes à 8 bits per byte.

After all preparation and calculation it's straightforward to send all data byte by byte and bit by bit! So if we take the example from above this would look something like this:

```
data:    1013  -> 0000'0011 1111'0101
bitMask:   10

total amount of bytes: 2
1. byte = 1111'0101
2. byte = 0000'0011
```

So while sending the data (here output in the browser) you are displaying the data in reverse! Because when you are receiving it you are changing it back and you get the right results!

```
<?php

    class binaryCoder {

        /* Properties */
        public $data;  // <-- save/receive data into this property
        public $bitMask = [];
        private $byteCount = 0x00;

        /* Constructor */
        public function __construct() {


        }

        /* Methods */
        public function writeData(array $data, array $bitMask) {

            $this->data = $data;
            $this->bitMask = $bitMask;
            $this->byteCount = array_reduce($this->bitMask, function($byteCount, $bits){
                return $byteCount + ceil($bits/8);
            }, 0x00);


            foreach(array_combine($this->bitMask, $this->data) as $mask => $data) {
                for($byteCounter = 0; $byteCounter < ceil($mask/8); $byteCounter++) {
                    $this->writeByte($data >> ($byteCounter*8));
                }
            }

        }

        public function readData(array $bitMask) {
            $this->bitMask = $bitMask;
            $byte = 0x00;


            foreach($this->bitMask as $key => $mask) {
                $message[$key] = "";
                for($byteCounter = 0; $byteCounter < ceil($mask/8); $byteCounter++, $byte++) {
                    $message[$key] = sprintf("%08d", $this->readByte($byte*8)) . $message[$key];
                }
            }

            $message = array_map("bindec", $message);
            print_r($message);

        }

        private function writeByte($byte) {
            for($bitCount = 0; $bitCount < 8; $bitCount++) {
                $this->writeBit((bool)($byte & (1 << $bitCount)));
            }
        }

        private function readByte($bytePosition) {
            $byte = 0x00;

            for($bitCount = 0; $bitCount < 8; $bitCount++) {
                $byte |= (int)$this->readBit($bytePosition+$bitCount) << $bitCount;
            }
            return decbin($byte);
        }

        private function writeBit($bit) {
            echo ($bit?1:0);  // --> send/write data to dest. (Note it's reversed!)
        }

        private function readBit($bit) {
            return $this->data[$bit];
        }


    }


    /* Testing */
    $binaryTransmitter = new binaryCoder();
    $binaryTransmitter->writeData([1013, 1, 3, 51209], [10, 1, 2, 19]);
    $binaryTransmitter->data = "10101111110000001000000011000000100100000001001100000000";  //received data 
    $binaryTransmitter->readData([10, 1, 2, 19]);

?>
```

output:

```
10101111110000001000000011000000100100000001001100000000 //note output here is reversed!
Array ( [0] => 1013 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 51209 )
```